# How to add img tags to button text using haml and erb button_to helper function

Tags: ruby, haml, erb

I have this piece of code (ruby haml)

`= button_to tr('single_sign_on') , '/something/something0', method: :post, class: "btn-SSO"`

Now I need to insert 2 icons to the button text.
Any idea how to do that. I have zero experience with this tech & codebase.
This doesn't have to use the `button_to` helper function.
Can be just plain haml (i'm assuming I would have to wrap this in a form then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helper takes a block as a parameter where you can add icons https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

```rb
= button_to '/something/something0', method: :post, class: "btn-SSO" do
  = tr('single_sign_on')   
  i.fa.fa-save # example
```

Comment: Thanks. Translation needs the equals sign but the rest is spot on.